# How to use two buttons in a formular with click event

Tags: jquery, css

i want to have the opportunity to save the formular on two different positions on a button with a click event, but only button1 works.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button1" value="Save">       
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button2" value="Save"> 
$("#button1, #button2").click(function()
{..}
```

Comment: what do you exactly want to perform same function for two different buttons ??

Comment: yes, same function on two buttons

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's no reason why the code shown would work for only one of the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**Insert jquery** And Complete jquery Function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
$("#button1, #button2").click(function()
{
alert('Button Click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button1" value="Save">       
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button2" value="Save">
```

Comment: How does this fix the OP's problem that "only button1 works"? (Obviously they must already be including jQuery if the function works for one of the buttons.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you,

```
 $('#button1').add('#button2').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
 });
```

Comment: Why would that make any difference? `"#button1, #button2"` is a valid selector.

Comment: No both are almost same, as OP said  **$("#button1, #button2").click(function()** isn't working. so I suggested this to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('click',"#button1,#button2",function(){
    alert('one');
});
```

Or another way you can do this.

```
function btnClick(){
    /* Your button click code */
}

/* Call that function on first button click */
$("#button1").click(function(){
     btnClick();
});

/* Call the same function again on first button click */
$("#button2").click(function(){
     btnClick();
});
```

Comment: How does this fix the OP's stated problem that "only button1 works"?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to bind a function in multiple button

first one

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    alert("button :"+e.id);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="2">Button2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="3">Button3</button>
```

second way

```js
$('#button1, #button2').click(function() {
    // You can use `this` to refer to the source element, for instance:
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button1" value="Save">       
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button2" value="Save">
```

third Way

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(e) { 
alert("hello"); //with common class
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button" value="Save">       
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button" value="Save">
```

another way

```js
function doClick(e) { 
   alert("hello");
}
$('#button1').click(doClick);
$('#button2').click(doClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button1" value="Save">       
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg rounded metro btn-primary" id="button2" value="Save">
```

Comment: Your second way is what the OP is already doing. But in any case, perhaps you could update your answer to note how any of these options address the OP's stated problem that "only button1 works"?

Comment: what do you mean by only button1 works OP said that he wants two button work with the same function. .or do you mean that on button will trigger at a time same function??

Comment: I mean that the OP said that their existing code already works for button1 but not button2 even though they used the `"#button1,#button2"` selector. (There must be something going on with their code that isn't shown in the question.)

Comment: yes you are right .OP's way is correct it should work may be Op is not sharing the full code